# How to detect eyes and mouth in android

Tags: android

For detecting face I am reffering to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html#. I am able to find eye differece and midpoint.But I am unable to show mouth position(lip position).

Comment: You have to use OpenCV for that.

Comment: try to imlement open cv lib for that'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only calculate approximate distance to mouth, manually.

This answer in link tell you more detailed: [Android - Face feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783969/android-face-feature-detection)

Also i recommend you use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for this purposes.

Answer (score 2):

opencv is best lib for working with face and eye Detection Using opencv you can do:
 http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/eye-detection-and-tracking/
Example Code:
http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/